# Observable Promises .then is not a function

Tags: php, angular, typescript

I'm setting up an Angular Application. My Data comes from an elastic.php file.
Every time I execute my Search function, i'm getting this error.

```
this.http.Search(...).then is not a function
```

I'm thinking about the problem is about the observable. Maybe it must be a toPromise() function.
But I'm not sure about this and I'm not sure how to handle this correctly.

**http.service.ts**

```
  Search(body: any): any {
    const proxyBody = {
      path: 'doctyp136,doctyp135,doctyp134/_search',
      body: body
    };

     return this.http.post( environment.elastic_url, proxyBody, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })} ).subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });

   }
```

**elastic.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Elastic php proxy
 */
 const ELASTIC_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:9210/fud_fret_web/";

/*
* 1) Gather infos from 
*/
// Takes raw data from the request
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Converts it into a PHP object
$data = json_decode($json);

$elasticSubPath = $data['path'];
$elasticBody = $data['body'];

/*
 * 2) Submit CURL request to local elasticsearch (http://localhost:9210/api/fud_fret_web/)
 */
$url = ELASTIC_BASE_URL . $elasticSubPath;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $elasticBody);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

/*
 * 3) Return (and transform?) results
 */
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $response;
exit;
```

**Search.comopnent.ts**

```
    this.http.Search(query).then(
      (response: any) => { ....
```

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simpler to just return an observable and subscribe to it. Unless i am misunderstanding your goal?

**http.service.ts**

```
 Search(body: any): Observable<any> {
    const proxyBody = {
      path: 'doctyp136,doctyp135,doctyp134/_search',
      body: body
    };

     return this.http.post( environment.elastic_url, proxyBody, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })})
   }
```

**Search.comopnent.ts**

```
this.http.Search(query).subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log(data);
    }
)
```

Alternatively if you really want it to be a promise you can convert it to one with the following.

**http.service.ts**

```
Search(body: any): Promise<any> {
    const proxyBody = {
      path: 'doctyp136,doctyp135,doctyp134/_search',
      body: body
    };

     return this.http.post( environment.elastic_url, proxyBody, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })}).toPromise()
   }
```

**Search.comopnent.ts**

```
this.http.Search(query).then(
    data => {
        console.log(data);
    }
)
```

Comment: Still getting this Error ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}